# Disable ALL webkit prefixes in Gecko/Firefox

Tags: css

As a professional web designer/developer if I need to use something that is considered experimental I implement all the relevant prefixes for all the browser engines.

Unfortunately there is a significant enough number of people posing as web designers/developers who *only* implement the `-webkit-` prefixes because they only "test" in one maybe two browsers.

That in turn led to the already incapable "leadership" at some browser vendors to start implementing each other's prefixes.

So in short is there a way to tell Gecko/Waterfox to *only* use it's own prefixes? A working answer would not resort to some convoluted JavaScript.

Comment: Is there a specific webkit-prefixed property that you're seeing apply in a Gecko-based browser? I haven't seen this behavior before so I'm curious.

Comment: @JonUleis `display: -webkit-box;` in one example. Newer versions of Safari *still* do not correctly support flexbox and so fixing issues in Safari 5.1 (yeah...) fixes those same issues in newer versions.

Comment: Interesting! It looks like Gecko also interprets `display: -webkit-flex` which renders seemingly the same as `display: flex`, so maybe the key is using that property on the next line after `display: -webkit-box` for maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

An end user can do this by opening about:config and setting `layout.css.prefixes.webkit` to `false`. An author will need to remove the offending declarations from the stylesheet with JavaScript — Gecko does not provide any author-side switch that can be flipped to disable those declarations (nor does any other layout engine for that matter).

As annoyed as I am that the other browser vendors bent over and implemented `-webkit-` prefixes, I'd still put most of the blame on the widespread misuse of prefixes resulting in the WebKit monoculture. Note that *no other* vendor prefix has had to be implemented this way — *only* WebKit's, so saying that vendors have started implementing "each other's prefixes" isn't quite accurate.

And the ones losing out aren't the irresponsible authors or the browser vendors, but the web and its users as a whole. A browser vendor could make a stand by refusing to make their product compatible with things that in an ideal world they shouldn't have to, and end users will just move to a browser where the web actually works (i.e. a WebKit-based browser), thereby fueling the WebKit monoculture. Or, they could do their best to maintain compatibility with the web in its current state so users don't have to worry about sites not working in their product, and in the meantime resolve to find a different approach to "shipping" experimental features in a more foolproof way that is probably less likely to result in a fragmented web (which every vendor has done). There's a reason these compatibility fixes have even been [specced](https://compat.spec.whatwg.org).

So, yeah. I wouldn't call the other browser vendors "incapable". They're just acting in the best interests of their users and doing what they can to save the web from a WebKit monoculture.